# actionSearch for softkeyboard android does't work

Tags: android, keyboard

```
    txtSearch
        .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {

                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    text_search = txtSearch.getText().toString();                           
                    searchSong();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

       <EditText
            android:id="@id/txt_search"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/query_hint"
            android:imeActionLabel="Search"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:editable="true" 
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/hintsearch"
            android:textColorHint="@color/hintsearch"
            android:textSize="15sp" >
        </EditText>
```

I using default keyboard it work. But I test for orther keyboeard it's does't work.
I used soft keyboard: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vng.inputmethod.labankey

Comment: It might be a bug for that keyboard? What is the value of `actionId` in `onEditorAction`? Or doesn't it fire at all?

Comment: Yes. It's error for laban key. but defaut keyboard not error.